# What does いくつか mean in the phrase いくつかの種類?

Tags: words

I know `いくつ` means 'how old', but what does `いくつか` mean in the following sentence?

> 緑茶、紅茶、ウーロン茶など**いくつかの種類**に分けられる。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

いくつ in general means "how many"; this can also be applied to years to ask "how old" ("how many years") as you've pointed out.

か can be add to counter question words to mean "several ～".

> - ラーメン屋に学生が何人かいます。　→　There are several (people) students in the ramen restaurant.
> - 先週のお祭りに何個かのたこ焼きを食った。　→　I ate several takoyaki (balls) at the festival last week.
> - 緑茶、紅茶、ウーロン茶などいくつかの種類に分けられる。　→　Tea is divided into several kinds, such as green tea, black tea, and oolong tea.

Answer (score 2):

いくつ can also be used as an interrogative for indefinite number, that is, how many.
To use indefinite expressions in non-question, か is combined with it.

- いくつか - some number

  - いくつかの種類 - some number of kinds
- いつか - at some point (Of time)

  - いつか彼には知らせるつもりだった。- I was going to tell him at some point.
- なぜか - for some reason

  - 彼女はなぜかこの頃私を避けてる。 - She is avoiding me for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

> I know いくつ means how old

Without context, 「いくつ」 means "how many" far more often than it means "how old".

「いくつか」 means "some", "a few", "several", etc.